# How to configure the chinese support in my software?

Tags: c++, fltk

I am using `FLTK` to implement the user interface of my application. To implement the chinese support I am using the font `wenquanyi`. However when this font is configured the roman characters are displayed in a ugly way, and the roman numbers are displayed in a bold style. This is the best font to support a mixed implementation, roman characteres mixed with chinese characters?

Maybe the parameters that I am using to load the font are wrong

```
Fl::set_font(FL_HELVETICA, "-wenquanyi-wenquanyi bitmap song-medium-r-normal--0-0-100-100-p-0-iso10646-1");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Latin text mixed with Han characters has an typography requirement to appear proportional.  Modern media for some regions may prefer to mix layout forms but there is no single universal method.

Thus what you are actually seeking is tagging the metadata of the layout for Han & mixed form and for pure Latin form.

[image: Example different text layouts (credit: State Farm advert)]

The workaround would be to use two fonts and manage the context in your application.